# Single instance modules in JavaScript (TypeScript)

Tags: javascript, jestjs, state, global

I'm trying to define a simple assertion package in TypeScript so that assertions can be turned off during efficiency testing (and production eventually). Here's my attempt for a simple module:

```
let assertionsEnabled = true;

export function withAssertions<T>(val : boolean, body : () => T) : T {
    const savedEnabled = assertionsEnabled;
    try {
        assertionsEnabled = val;
        return body();
    } finally {
        assertionsEnabled = savedEnabled;
    }
}

export function assert(condition : () => boolean, message ?: string) {
    if (assertionsEnabled) {
        if (!condition()) {
            throw new Error("assertion failed" + (message ?? ""));
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that both the Jest test and the class being tested each import this module and they seem to end up with two different `assertionsEnabled` variables.  My test is encoded with

```
describe('building', () => {
    withAssertions(false, () => {
        ...
    });
});
```

and in the ADT, I have a bunch of assertions, but even though assertions are turned off in the Jest test, they are still on in the ADT.   I thought modules were supposed to have a single instance.  But obviously I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: I think using typescript as a tag would be a good idea

Comment: "*they seem to end up with two different `assertionsEnabled` variables.*" - are you sure there? Or does it just have an unexpected value? My guess would be that Jest is running the tests asynchronously, and you only disabled assertions during the *declaration* of the tests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm betting you have asynchronous stuff going on in your tests or stuff you instantiate as part of exporting from the module and it's happening before the jest stuff starts being executed.

Also, you might instead want to do a describeWithAssertion function instead, like so...

```js
function describeWithAssertion(
  ae: boolean,
  title: string,
  f: any // this should be specified better
) {
  const prevAE = assertionsEnabled;
  return describe(
    title,
    () => {
      beforeEach(() => assertionsEnabled = ae);
      afterEach(() => assertionsEnabled = prevAE);
      f();
    }
  );
}
```

This way, even if `f` contains async functionality, jest is worrying about it, not you.

Comment: I used `beforeAll` and `afterAll` instead but it worked also.  Thank you.